# How to check all array equal to some value in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, arrays

```
self.scope.savesectioneditmain = [self.scope.savesection2details,
                                  self.scope.editsection2,
                                  self.scope.savesection1details,
                                  self.scope.editsection1];
```

Based on above codes, I want to check all array value equal to `true` value.

```
if($.inArray(true, self.scope.savesectioneditmain) == 0)
```

I have tried `$inArray`, but `$inArray` checks only one condition, but I want to check all array value should be equal to `true`.

Comment: What property in array do you want to check actually? Is it your array contains some object? or some string? I've been confusing.

Comment: string true or false,My array contain true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
if(self.scope.savesectioneditmain.every(x => x == true)){
   //All elements are true
}
```